# Tableview ContentView Cell label constraints displaying incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

Currently I'm displaying two labels and view on a tableview contentview cell on my app. Without constraints, the labels display correctly on the device. However, when I add constraints to the labels in the storyboard, they always align to the left. I'm currently using top, bottom, leading/trailing (left & right), and have in other attempts also set height and width.

New Constraints storyboard:
[image: add new constrains storyboard photo]

However, when I run it on any device, it always looks like this:

Actual view:
[image: current view issue photo]

I'm wondering why this keeps happening. I want to avoid doing constraints programmatically in this app to show I can use storyboard, but this one problem has stumped me. I've tried reading up as much as I can, but I just can't get it to work. Any idea how to get it to look like the first picture, all the time when, adding constraints?

Comment: try to set trailing constraint as <= to standard. Don't hard code.

Comment: any update, is that working?

Comment: a little confused on what you're saying;  not sure how to do that/what that is?

Comment: Give your view (leading,top,height,width) and  give your time label ( left to view label ,top,height,width) similar for label below them give (leading,top,height,width). I hope you want time label to not overlap?

Comment: select trailing constraint, double click on that, it will be showing equal constraint (eg = 50) -> change that to <=50

Comment: am i constraining it to content view, no? keep getting issues

Comment: u can delete also trailing constraint.

Comment: so let me get this straight; i'll start with the view (the green circle), i constraint that in add new constraint with leading, top, and bottom (not changing anything; using their storyboard value and constrain to margins is checked). I check width and height, and just do that with the other items as well? so no trailing constraints?

Comment: Can you please tell what is the actual result you want?

Comment: i just want them to space that when on the screen.

Comment: @BitBeast - you want Green Circle on left, then "I am happy today" in the middle, then the date on the right? All on "one line"?

Comment: @Shubham yeah, so it'd look better on smaller devices

Comment: your both pics seems to be confusing, can you post the pic of the result you want ?